# Paste image from clipboard

Tags: java, html, applet, clipboard

I'm trying to paste image from clipboard in my website (like copy and paste). Appreciate if anyone could advice on this. Can I achieve this using HTML 5 or applet or any way. Any advice or any link for reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: *"Can I achieve this using .. applet"*  Yes.  But it would have to be digitally signed by you, and trusted by the user when prompted.  BTW - DYM that the image should be uploaded to the web site (e.g so others can see it later)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The scenario is my user need to screen shot their error and paste in my website. They don't want to paste the screen in paint or photoshop then convert it to image and and upload it in the website. Appreciate if you could share any links for reference for applet. Thanks

Comment: Try the [applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) wherein I have concentrated my 'best links' for applets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do it with JavaScript.

**JavaScript**

```
if (!window.Clipboard) {
   var pasteCatcher = document.createElement("apDiv1");
   pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
   pasteCatcher.style.opacity = 0;
   document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);
   pasteCatcher.focus();
   document.addEventListener("click", function() { pasteCatcher.focus(); });
} 

window.addEventListener("paste", onPasteHandler);

function onPasteHandler(e)
{
    if(e.clipboardData) {
        var items = e.clipboardData.items;
        if(!items){
            alert("Image Not found");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        if (items[i].kind === 'file' && items[i].type === 'image/png') {
            var blob = items[i].getAsFile(),
                source = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);

            pastedImage = new Image();
            pastedImage.src = source;

            pasteData();
            }
        }
    }
}

function pasteData()
{
    drawCanvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas1');
    ctx = drawCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640,480);
    ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
}
```

DIV

```
<div id="apDiv1" contenteditable='true'>Paste Test</div>
```

Comment: Word of warning, folks - this won't work under IE8 or earlier. Works fine in Firefox 20+ (could work in earlier versions, don't know for sure) and Chrome.

Comment: drawCanvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas1'); --->drawCanvas1 is which type of control here

Answer (score 0):

Even if applet is not signed, JNLP API is available.

```
ClipboardService cs = (ClipboardService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.ClipboardService");
Image c = (Image)cs.getContents().getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
```

Answer (score 0):

at first, making a file(image) server.

then using js to listen to paste event. 
code key word:

```
addEventListener 'paste' clipboard image
```

then using ajax upload to the file server. ajax resp the url.

finally making img tag by the url.

applet is out of date... ignore.